# "GET Variable to Segment URL Redirect" Plugin for EE2

Tags: url, plugins, expressionengine

Using EE2, this is the plugin in question: [GET Variable to Segment URL Redirect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/get-variable-to-segment-url-redirect)

This is exactly the plugin I need to solve a project problem, but I cannot get it to work. It doesn't do anything, and I'm sure its my own mistake but I cannot find any other helpful tidbits on this..

My form is:

```
<div id="sidebar">
               <div class="aliance">
                  <h2>Clergy</h2>
                  <a href="{path='PCP/partner_congregations/'}" class="more">Show All</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="http://alliance-marketing.madmonkdev2.com/index.php/PCP/congregation_list?State=21">Sort By</a>
                    <form  action="{path='PCP/congregation_list'}" method="get">
                     <select name="State">
                       {exp:gwcode_categories cat_id="16" incl_self="no"}
                           <option value="{cat_id}">&#123;cat_name&#125;</option>
                     {/exp:gwcode_categories&#}
                       </select>
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                   </form>
                     </li> 
                  </ul>
               </div>
```

Here's the plugin code:

```
{exp:get_segment_redirect get_variable=“State” base_url=”/PCP/”}
```

The URL it should be redirecting but doesn't:

```
http://blahblahblah.com/index.php/PCP/congregation_list?State=17
```

I simply have to be overlooking something real simple here.. Because it's not doing anything at all for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our discussion on Devot-ee http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/get-variable-to-segment-url-redirect/viewthread/10383, the cause of the issue was open and close quotation marks as a result of copying and pasting from another website (a common issue, hard to spot!).

Replacing these with straight quotes resulted in the plugin being called correctly.